# A Fibonacci Inequality

Tags: inequality, fibonacci-numbers

While attempting to seek new inequalities for Fibonacci numbers one was developed, empirically, but has a tighter bound than several comparable inequalities provide (Titu's, Cauchy's, etc). The inequality developed is:
$$ \frac{F_{n}^{6}}{F_{n+1}^{3} + F_{n+2}^{3}} + \frac{F_{n+1}^{6}}{F_{n}^{3} + F_{n+2}^{3}} + \frac{F_{n+2}^{6}}{F_{n}^{3} + F_{n+1}^{3}} \geq \frac{27}{2} \, F_{n} \, F_{n+1} \, F_{n+2}. $$ 
What is being asked for is assistance in finding some form of known inequality that will help prove this inequality presented.

Comment: What is the point in developing such inequalities, since the Fibonacci numbers have a simple closed form, and the given inequality can be checked just by exploiting it (or leaving it to a CAS)?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Valid questioning. The point to using Fibonacci, and known integer forms, is often to "test" the inequalities developed, as is the case here. The value of "27" on the right-hand side is associated with the Fibonacci numbers, however.

Answer (score 1):

Asymptotically, 
$$
F_n \approx \dfrac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt{5}}, \quad\mbox{ where }\;\varphi = \dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$

Then we have

$$
LHS \approx \dfrac{\varphi^{3n}}{\sqrt{5}^3} \left(\dfrac{1}{\varphi^{3}+\varphi^{6}} + 
\dfrac{\varphi^{6}}{1+\varphi^{6}} + 
\dfrac{\varphi^{12}}{1+\varphi^{3}} \right) \approx 5.589 \varphi^{3n}.
$$

$$
RHS \approx\dfrac{\varphi^{3n}}{\sqrt{5}^3} \cdot \dfrac{27\varphi^3}{2}  \approx 5.115 \varphi^{3n}.
$$

Playing with small $n$, one can improve constant $\dfrac{27}{2}$ to $\dfrac{486}{35}$ (then we'll have equality for $n=2$).